# Displaying CardView as a Dialog in Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-cardview

I am looking to display a `CardVeiw` that displays some information for the user. At the same time, I need its behavior to be similar to a dialog, and at the same time, I  need to enable the user to click on the left and right buttons as shown bellow and flip the `CardView` to display another `CardView` with richer Content such as some detailed description... Here is an example:

So far I knew that I can create a `Dialog`, but my content could be scrollable. So it might not be a good practice to use a `Dialog` in this case (According to https://material.io/guidelines/components/dialogs.html#dialogs-alerts).

[image]

So I would like to know what are the best practices for this problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

set dialog window background to transparent `dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);`

Comment: how to do that with XML?